# Need to use two bitcoin core but issue with syncing

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Need to know how we can use two bitcoin node for example. I do have two bitcoin full nodes A and B. Created wallet address at A and has all transaction details at wallet.db in node A. But I need to keep PK in DB and take those and send request to B node, but it fails as it dont have all transaction details, I dont want to re scan B node every time, is there any way we can achieve this. So that i dont need to worry on which node my request is going.

Thanks,
Prad

Comment: I think you have to explain better what you are trying to achieve. You want A and B to both be able to spend coins from the same 'wallet' ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to be node independent. If user creates wallet and say it got created on A node, will keep private key in DB, and any further transaction can be done on A or B. If we want to do on B, node B need to have all transaction history ( which is in wallet.db file of A node). So Node B need to sync before doing any transactions. I dont want to use syncing everytime. Any alternate way like peering, addnode properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can just copy the wallet files from node A to node B.

Note that this is not recommended and may result in strange behavior. You will not have any labels synced across the two nodes as they really are operating independently of each other. They just have wallet files that have the same private keys.

---

If you just want node B to have the transaction history from node A, you can import addresses from node A into node B so that node B is watching the blockchain for those addresses.

Comment: I dont want to use scan here to watch transactions, thats the problem. Trying  to see what else option to get transaction details.

Comment: You only need to rescan once on import. The node will continue watching for transactions to those addresses whenever it is online and it will scan as it catches up the blockchain when you turn it on later.